# UWP Community Toolkit issue

Tags: uwp, nuget-package

Ive been trying to use the radialprogressbar from the UWP Community Kit 
Ive downloaded it and added to my toolbox 
all the tools did show up but when I try to use it 
it keep showing these errors

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you show your project target version and microsoft.netcore.universalwindows version because you are using microsoft community toolkit 2.1 view dependency of toolkit2.1 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/

Comment: I ve fixed the problem 
Its the SDK 
Btw is there a group learning UWP ?? 
Iam really struggles when study these alone

Comment: @StrypperVandelJason take a look at MVA, for example [this course](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541) may help you.